# includeCSS vs. includeCSSLibs

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I'm currently reading the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#includecsslibs-array) of TYPO3 and I found properties in the global `config.page` setting which are called `includeCSSLibs` and `includeJSLibs`.

**My question is:**
Whats the difference between these properties against their equivalent `includeCSS` and `includeJS`?

I didn't caught any differences in my frontend output, except that the "Libs" are placed in front of the default definitions.
Is this all about it?

Does anybody know more about this feature? Or are there any explanatory links?

Thanks for your help.
Best regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is the order of inclusion. Anything included with the `Libs` variants *will be rendered before other, non-lib inclusions*.

Comment: And that's it? Well, thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Yep, that's it :)